# Proving global minimum when optimizing surface area of an open top box

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, convex-analysis

Given the task to optimize the surface area of an open top box, we find the need to optimize 3 x*y+ 2x*z + 4y*z for all non-negative x, y and z where x*yz = 3. The solution obtained is (2, 1, 1.5).  However, is there a simpler way of proving that this point is a global minimum without using second derivatives?

By extension, since the process of optimizing the surface area of a box always leads to function of similar format but with different constants, is there an axiom that states that the critical point  found when optimizing said surface area is always the global minimum?

Attempt at a solution:
My intuition tells me that the most straight forward way is to prove convexity, which I'm unable to do so as the function seems like a sum of 3 "saddle" functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using the AM-GM inequality we get
$$\frac{3xy+2xz+4yz}{3}\geq\sqrt[3]{24(xyz)^2}$$ with $$xyz=3$$